# self navigate react page goes into infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, navigateurl

Have control which navigate to same page with different values in url

Case 1 - Below code invokes useEffect infinite times after clicking navigate

```
const queryValues = queryString.parse(search);
const { trip } = queryValues;

useEffect(() => {
 console.log('Calling infinite times');
},[trip]));
```

Case 2 - If I change code to below then useEffect never call again any updates to url by clicking navigation button

```
useEffect(() => {
 const queryValues = queryString.parse(search);
 const { trip } = queryValues;
 console.log('Calling infinite times');
},[]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing bracket in both useEffect cases.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const queryValues = queryString.parse(search);
 const { trip } = queryValues;
 console.log('Calling infinite times');
},[])
```